# Adding new paragraph after sibilings

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am just working on a chat application and using jQuery for client site.Now,when I use this line for creating a paragraph,it adds the new paragraph before its siblings.So how can I add it after them.I used br tag but got the same result.Here`s the fiddle for the code:

[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/shrinivas93/atoejgjd/1/)

and this is the main jQuery line that I want to change.

```
$('#answer').html("<p>" + bla + "</p>");
```

Thanks.

Comment: Have you thought about using `document.createElement('p')` and using `appendChild()` ?

Comment: I haven`t used that in real projects yet.Could you give more specific example please?

Comment: @NewToJS - since the OP is using the jQuery library, it wouldn't make sense here to use the native JS functions - jQuery already provides this functionality and can maintain it's behavior across browsers (something that normal JS sometimes has difficulties )

Comment: @Lix I like to offer pure javascript with jQuery and since both are tagged I think my comment is relevant. Sometimes learning pure javascript can help understand how jQuery works since jQuery is nothing but precoded functions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using the `html` function will actually replace the entire HTML content of the `#answer` element.

In order to *append* the `<p>` element you need to use the [`append()` function](http://api.jquery.com/append/)

> `.append(content)`
>    Insert content, specified by the parameter, to the end of each element in the set of matched elements.

```
$('#answer').append("<p>" + bla + "</p>");
```

Here is an [updated version of your fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/atoejgjd/2/).
I changed two things with your code:

1. You were attempting to manually append the new message with
   `bla = bla +  $('#answer').html();`. This is not necessary since we will always be adding only the new content that is in the `bla` variable.
2. You were overriding the entire contents of your `#answer` element each time the user pressed enter. All you need to do is add the new content that was in the input field.

Answer (score 0):

Use jQuery append to add HTML content at the end. And in your case, simply fetch the contents sent by the user, present in the `#send` element, compose in `<p>` tags and append it to the `#answer` element.

In all, use the line

```
$('#answer').append("<p>" + $('#send').val() + "</p>");
```

And it solves your problem.